# Firebase listAll return error 'An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get a list of all the objects in my Firebase Storage, but upon calling the `.listAll` like so:

```
Storage.storage().reference().listAll { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'An unknown error occurred, please check the server response.'

Firebase pods are all updated, and no matter the storage reference path, I get the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is that you forgot to set the rules to be `version 2`, which is required for the list operations to work. From the documentation on [listing files on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files):

> The list API is only allowed for Rules version 2

So make sure that you have this as the first line in the security rules for your storage in the Firebase console:

```
rules_version = "2";
```